# Sharepoint 2010 OfficialFileUrl is Always NULL

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, records-management, records-center

I am trying to Get the **RecordCenterURL** from **Sharepoint2010**,

1. I have created Connection to Connect RecordCenter or DocumentRepository. I used this [LINK](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ee424395%28v=office.14%29.aspx)
2. When I try to Retrieve the OfficialFileUrl from Application, Its always return NULL value.

I have used this sample Code , Please help me for this Issue.

```
 string URL = "http://inblr-iifw8sv03:31521";

                SPSite site = new SPSite(URL);
                string recordCenterUrl = string.Empty;

                if (site.WebApplication.OfficialFileUrl != null)// This is Always NULL
                {
                    recordCenterUrl = site.WebApplication.OfficialFileUrl.ToString().
                        Replace("_vti_bin/officialfile.asmx", string.Empty);
                }

                Console.WriteLine("URL Found " + recordCenterUrl);
                Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

To get an official file host you need to use

```
site.webApplication.OfficialFileHosts
```

This contains an array of filehost.
You can easy use powershell to create get and manipulate these hosts

For example to get an official host you can user this function

```
Function Get-SPOfficialFileHost{
[CmdletBinding()]
param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ValueFromPipeline=$true, Position=0)][Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPWebApplicationPipeBind] $WebApplication,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [string] $Name
    )

    $WebApp = $WebApplication.Read()
    $officialFileHost =  $webapp.OfficialFileHosts | ? { $_.OfficialFileName -eq $Name }
    return $officialFileHost
}
```

or Create

```
Function New-SPOfficialFileHost{
[CmdletBinding()]
param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ValueFromPipeline=$true, Position=0)][Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPWebApplicationPipeBind] $WebApplication,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [string] $Name,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [string] $Url,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [string] $Action,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [string] $Explanation,    
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [switch] $ShowOnSendToMenu
    )

    $WebApp = $WebApplication.Read()

    $officialFileHost = Get-SPOfficialFileHost -WebApplication $WebApplication -Name $Name

    if ($officialFileHost -eq $null) {
        Write-Host "Add new Send To Connections..." -NoNewline
        [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPOfficialFileHost] $officialFileHost = New-Object "Microsoft.SharePoint.SPOfficialFileHost"
        $officialFileHost.Action = [Enum]::Parse([Microsoft.SharePoint.SPOfficialFileAction], $Action)
        $officialFileHost.Explanation = $Explanation
        $officialFileHost.OfficialFileName = $Name
        $officialFileHost.OfficialFileUrl = $Url.TrimEnd("/") + "/_vti_bin/officialfile.asmx" 
        $officialFileHost.ShowOnSendToMenu = [bool]::Parse($true)
        $webapp.OfficialFileHosts.Add($officialFileHost)
        $webapp.Update()
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green " - Done."   
    }
}
```